# What is the stability of Pregnenolone in various mediums?

Tags: solubility, solutions

I have some pregnenolone powder that I want to dissolve it in to a liquid medium for later human ingestion, some potential medium choices would be: alcohol, fruit juice, water, olive oil. I am trying to find out what mediums it will be most soluble and stable in. Please help, I am not a chemist and have not been able to find the answer to this anywhere, the best I have found is that it should mix in oil well - but I do not know how that would effect the shelf-life. I just have this powder that I want to distribute in to a medium for easy supplementation. If you can help, then thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pregnenolone has a water solubility of less than 1mg/ml so forget fruit juices and water if you want it dissolved. According to this article it is soluble in ethyl alcohol at 19mg/ml http://www.jpharmsci.org/article/S0095-9553(15)32106-5/pdf

I'm not finding any data that suggests it is chemically unstable in neutral solution.

Comment: Thank you Waylander! That table is exactly what I needed.